# EC2 - High CPU Utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu, amazon-cloudwatch

I checked EC2 CPU utilization and it went nealy 100% at intervals for 3hours. It happened the past 3months too. when I checked run-command the command output shows "cloud-watch-agant" at the top followed by "w3wp" and "MsMpEng". what is likey the cause for this? is "cloud-warch-agent" using high cpu utilization?

Comment: Are you using the CloudWatch agent to send custom log files to CloudWatch? If not, you could simply deactivate it.

Answer (score 0):

I may be barking up the wrong tree here but isn't the cloud watch a logging agent?... I've not touched EC2 in a long while so cant remember.

Might be worth checking if your storage logs are just too big and are causing issues when logs are being added... again i could be wrong

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering. May I possibly ask what kind of logs should I delete. I've been searching the whole day and I still can't find the log. where exactly can i see the logs?

Comment: Amazon CloudWatch agent can be configured to send your own custom logs to CloudWatch. For example, you might have an application producing logs on EC2 instances. Instead of logging into each instance to retrieve logs, the agent can periodically send logs to CloudWatch Logs. @JohnDeki Do you know whether your system has been configured to do this?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).